# Changing Java Version for a Specific Program

Tags: java, batch-file, parameters

If I have more than one version of Java installed can I specify the version I want to kick a program off with via batch file, or do I have to change my environment variable? If I have to change the environment path will the programs that are currently using the other version stop working? I'm thinking no but wanted to make sure.

I have the following batch file in place to change versions on the fly but it doesn't seem to work- http://pastebin.com/4S6xYHan

Edit- Updated batch file.

Comment: Your problem maybe `GOTO :end`. Try `GOTO end` instead (no colon when referencing label). The label must still be declared as `:end`.

Comment: At least in NT-based Windows versions, changes in the environment made by a batch are isolated to the batch run. They don't change system-wide and therefore will not affect other batch runs (even of the same batch). For system-wide changes, you need to use the dialog pointed out by Fede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your batch file executes the Java program as:

```
java  com.stackexchange.MyProgram  argument1 argument2 etc
```

You can change it to execute it using a specific Java installation as:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java.exe"  com.stackexchange.MyProgram  argument1 argument2 etc
```

Or you can declare a variable and use it (this is useful if you have a **master** batch file that sets up the environment for your *mini* batch files):

```
:: In master batch ::
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin

:: In mini batch ::
"%JAVA_HOME%\java.exe"  com.stackexchange.MyProgram  argument1 argument2 etc
```

Comment: Thank you! The first answer worked perfectly, but I can't get the "master batch" solution to work. 
Here are my batch files-
Master: http://pastebin.com/eD9s8ekq
Program Kicker: http://pastebin.com/qP1papMq

Comment: Did you see my comments on your question?

Comment: I'm curious. When I add a check for the Java it still says 1.6.0_20 but then it references the one I'm trying to use, which is 16.3. Does the screenshot below mean that it's running with 16.3? http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=261ivki&s=8#.U6xbYrH5dbQ
---
Edit- I just did. Going to make the changes now, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be running the version I specified. If I try- 
--- 
'@echo off
TITLE Java v.6u13
"C:\Program Files\JavaTest\jre6\bin\java.exe" -version
PAUSE' 
---
I get-
---
'java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)'

Comment: Then you have that version installed on that path. Try downloading and extracting the old version and run the `-version` command on it.

Comment: You're right. I checked the "javacpl.exe" in that folder and it looks like my counterpart actually installed the same version but in a different location, instead of installing 6u13 in that location. Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You batch file is ok.

You can use `SET` command on a terminal to set your `JAVA_HOME` and also add it to your `path` variable and that's enough to run an app with the jdk you want.

Remember that if you set it through terminal the variable will work on that terminal and last during that terminal is open.

If you want to cover the scope for you SO you need to set in windows variables:

[image]

For linux you need to use export command the variables

Comment: Here's what I get when I run my batch file-
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2uep7o7&s=8#.U6xLP7H5dbQ

So, according to what you're saying, that should be correct because it only changes it for that instance console right? If so, how then do I kick off ANOTHER batch file which has the following arguments inside of it-
"java -Xms64m -Xmx128m -cp" + a bunch of jar dependencies.

Can I just add that program name to start it after I set the Java version inside the console vs the batch? Will that work?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it for a specific instance of a program why not specify the full path, e.g.

```
if "%1" == "6.20" (

'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin\java.exe' -version
```

)